# WSO2 MI Validate Mediator

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-micro-integrator, wso2-esb

I cannot properly configure validation based on JSON schema.
Validate Mediator failed with the following:

```
Unsupported Operation org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: Unsupported Operation
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMTextImpl.getInputStream(OMTextImpl.java:422)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.ValidateMediator.mediate(ValidateMediator.java:231)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:109)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:71)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:158)
    at org.apache.synapse.api.Resource.process(Resource.java:342)
    at org.apache.synapse.api.API.process(API.java:463)
    at org.apache.synapse.api.AbstractApiHandler.apiProcess(AbstractApiHandler.java:93)
    at org.apache.synapse.api.AbstractApiHandler.dispatchToAPI(AbstractApiHandler.java:71)
    at org.apache.synapse.api.rest.RestRequestHandler.dispatchToAPI(RestRequestHandler.java:84)
    at org.apache.synapse.api.rest.RestRequestHandler.process(RestRequestHandler.java:70)
    at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.process(RESTRequestHandler.java:54)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:344)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseMessageReceiver.receive(SynapseMessageReceiver.java:101)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processNonEntityEnclosingRESTHandler(ServerWorker.java:375)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processEntityEnclosingRequest(ServerWorker.java:434)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:182)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: The following resource:
<validate cache-schema="true" source="json-eval($.msg)">
 <schema key="conf:myresources/ValidationResource.json"/>
 <on-fail>
  <payloadFactory media-type="json">
   <format>{"Error":$1"}</format>
   <args>
    <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:ERROR_MESSAGE"/>
   </args>
  </payloadFactory>
  <property name="HTTP_SC" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="400"/>
  <respond/>
 </on-fail>
</validate>

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the **Media Type** of the **schema file** as **application/json**[1].After creating the artifacts from the Integration Studio, open the created carbon application and check relevant **artifact file** of the schema.
Then it should be configured as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><resources>
<item>
    <file>ValidationResource.json</file>
    <path>/_system/config/myresources</path>
    <mediaType>application/json</mediaType>
    <properties/>
</item>
```

[1] https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/references/mediators/validate-Mediator/#examples_1

Comment: That's working. Thanks!